# How can I see backend logs in a published Corvid site

Tags: velo

I'm creating a site with Corvid by Wix and I'm having trouble debugging my backend code. I have no problem with using `console.log` in the front end but I can't see my logs from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search on "wix site monitoring" will answer all your questions related to this.

Also see this: https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-about-site-monitoring